# Замена функции rand() в PHP.. Вопрос чисто теоретический.

Tags: php

Стало интересно, можно ли написать функцию которая бы генерировало рандомное число. Без использовании встроенных функции в PHP (**rand**, **mt_rand** и т.д)?

Comment: можно, в чем проблема?

Comment: @Ильгиз Хамитов чисто теоритический ответ: будет фигня :)  
Нужно, для начала, определиться с такой штукой, как [источник случайных чисел][1].  


  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB#.D0.98.D1.81.D1.82.D0.BE.D1.87.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.BA.D0.B8_.D1.81.D0.BB.D1.83.D1.87.D0.B0.D0.B9.D0.BD.D1.8B.D1.85_.D1.87.D0.B8.D1.81.D0.B5.D0.BB

Comment: функцию генерирующую рандомное число написать нельзя, увы.

Comment: А как же на стороне PHP написан модуль?

Comment: это функция генерирующая псевдослучайное число. Близко к случайному устройство /dev/random в linux. чисто теоретически на него можно настоящий генератор подключить.

Answer (score 4):

```
function myrand($a = 0, $b = 1, $seed = null) {
    $N = 0.123456789;

    if (!is_null($seed)) {
        $N = $seed - (int)$seed;
    }

    $N = $N * 3571; 
    $N = $N - (int)$N * 1.0;

    return (int)($a + ($b - $a + 1) * $N);
}
```

Ищите лучше! http://www.cyberforum.ru/post3798471.html